# Question on how to prove the following is NOT a boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

So I am given two binary operations $\times$ and ${+}$, such that given two values, say $A$ and $B$, $A{\times}B$ would equal $C$, where $C$ is the maximum value between $A$ and $B$, and $A{+}B$ would map to $D$ where $D$ is the minimum value for $A$ and $B$.

I know in order to prove that it is a boolean algebra I need to show that it follows the following five properties: Association, Distribution, Commutation, and that there exists an Identity and a Complement.

It has been given to me that the operations are NOT boolean algebras and it falls on me to prove why, but I'm not sure if I am approaching it incorrectly or what but I cannot seem to prove it. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: We can not tell if you are approaching it incorrectly if we can not see your approach.  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I just tried plugging in values and attempting to check the properties.  II allowed A < B, making B = C in the following:  For example, the distributive property states that A x (B + C) = (A x C) + (A x B).  If you simplify that, you find that A x (B) = (AxB) + (AxB) since B = C that should be legal.  Then you have A x B = B + B (since AxB = B because B > A).  AxB would then equal B (again, B > A) and B+B = B, giving B=B.  I attempted to do that for all 5 properties and found that each one of them work, which means I am doing something wrong, sorry for not showing my work originally

Comment: Not completely sure I follow your reasoning, but it looks like that by imposing $B=C$ you are effectively restricting your algebra to two distinct elements.  Then, clearly, maximum is OR and minimum is AND, so that everything works.  But for three distinct elements, as suggested by @quasi...

Comment: I replied in this thread before I saw quasi's response.  However, when checking with three values 0, A, and 1 as he suggested, I still found that it works for association, distribution, and commutation.  I feel like I am not properly testing for identity and complements, but I don't think I'm doing that properly so any advice in that direction would be much appreciated

Comment: So, then, what is your understanding of "Identity", and "Complement" here?  What are the $\times$ and $+$ identities of $0, A, $ and $1$, and what *are their complements*?

Comment: the complement of x (the maximum operator) would be negative infinity and the complement of the + operator would be positive infinity, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $S = \{0,x,1\}$, where $0 < x < 1$.

Check the axioms.

One of them fails.

Comment: I checked distributive, commutative, and associative and they all seem to work just fine for me.  Looking back at my notes I'm starting to wonder if I fully grasp how to check for identities and compliments.  If it fails for one of the first three (distributive, commutative, associative) could you possibly show me how, and if it fails one of the last two could you give me a better idea of how I would approach showing that? Thank you

Comment: @John Doe: What's the complement of $x$?

Comment: The complement of x would be all values not between 0 and 1, correct?

Comment: The set $S$ only contains $3$ values. There are no other elements.

Comment: By definition, a complement of $x$ is some element $y \in S$ such that what is true?

Comment: My understanding of a complement is that for a given set S, the complement to that set would be all elements not in that.  For example, if the universal set was the domain of all integers, and I allowed a set A to be all the positive integers A = {1, 2, 3...}, then the complement of A would be all the integers from negative infinity to 0.  I'm not sure if that really answered the question you posed to me or not, I may have misunderstood

Comment: No, these elements are not sets. They're just atomic elements with an order relation, together with the two operations, max and min.

Comment: For example, $x$ might be a number, say $x = 1/2$.

Comment: With those 3 elements, you can make a $3\times 3$ "multiplication" table (using max for the $\times$ operation), and you can make a $3\times3$ "addition" table (using min for the $+$ operation).

Comment: In which case the complement would be all real numbers, excluding 0, 1/2, and 1.  So in order for the complement to exist making this a boolean algebra, S + S^c = the Identity of S.  Which brings me back to being confused on what the identity is then.  Like I know for operators like the addition symbol (in regards to this question "+" denotes something else so I'm trying to avoid it) the identity would be 0 since any number plus - equals the original number.  So would the identity for the + operation (minimum) be positive infinity? since any number, a, a+(infinity) = a?

Comment: You are missing a key point. The algebra being tested has only 3 elements. There are no other elements. Every operation between two of those 3 elements must yield a result which is one of those 3 elements.

Comment: In particular, a complement of a given element (if it exists), must be one of those 3 elements. The complement of $0$ is $1$. Why? The complement of $1$ is $0$. Why? The complement of $x$ would have to be some element $y \in \{0,x,1\}$ such that 
$$\min(x,y) = 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;\max(x,y)=1$$

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see. So since there does not exist an element in the set S that is both greater than 1/2 and less than 1/2, then there does not exist a complementary element for 1/2, making the + and x operators not holding all 5 properties of a boolean algebra?

Comment: Yes, now you have it.

Comment: you are a Godsend.  Truly, truly an amazing person.  Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, it's not so much the lack of an element which is both less than 1/2 and greater than 1/2. The logic is more like this . . .
$$$$
If y is a complement of $1/2$, then
$$\min(1/2,y) = 0 \implies y = 0$$
$$\max(1/2,y) = 1 \implies y = 1$$
contradiction ($y$ can't be simultaneously $0$ and $1$).